# Moving object inside MacBook: is it a big problem?

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware

When I tilt my MacBook, I can hear a moving object inside it (like a screw or grain). It should either be something that belongs inside and for some reason got loose, or something from the outside that entered the MacBook (via the fan?).

I plan to go to an Apple Store to get it repaired, but is it an urgent issue? Could I damage parts inside my computer?

Comment: Maybe try to *gently* shake the object out a vent, if it sounds small enough to fit.  (But getting it stuck in a fan near a vent could be worse.)

Comment: Retina or pre-retina unibody? In my 2009 and 2012, sometimes I can hear the hard drive cable hit the back case (which sounds a little like something loose)

Comment: @Undo More recent laptop, retina.

Answer (score 15):

If the object is metal, it has the potential to short circuit something and possibly cause an expensive repair, especially if it shorts the system board. Even if the object is not metal, if it can get in the fan it may have potential to damage it.

I would immediately shutdown the computer and take it to an Apple Store or qualified repair center if you cannot investigate yourself.

Comment: For a cheap netbook, I would recommend shaking the device for amusement; but yeah, it's probably not good to do that with your MacBook. ;-)